# How to remove an item in an array/list in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary of arrays and would like to delete an item in the array by value for a specific key

For example:

```
xyz = {'250': ['6981', '8071'], '7759': ['2290', '6554', '3402']}
```

I want to delete `3402` from `7759: ['2290', '6554', '3402']`

Comment: `xyz['7759'].remove('3402')`…!?

Comment: Is just for this specific instance or is there a general pattern to the removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are use a key/value pair. So you can use:

```
xyz['7759'].remove('3402')
```

xyz['7759'] will give you access to the list ['2290', '6554', '3402'] and the remove function will remove the first item in the list whose value is '3402'.